# Android getView() not being called properly?

Tags: android

For some reason, the getView() method isn't being called the full amount. It should be called 10 times. But it isnt...

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    res = getResources();
    searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
//  button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFriendList);

    friendList = new ArrayList<Friend>();

    nameBlock = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
    descBlock = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
    //imageBlock = res.getIntArray(R.array.images);

    int size = nameBlock.length;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        Log.d("FREINDADD", "Freind Added" + i);
        friendList.add(new Friend(nameBlock[i], descBlock[i], imageBlock[i]));
    }
    Log.i("Application", "Application started succesfully...");

    setListAdapter(new VirtuAdapter(this));

    searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            friendList.clear();
            textlength = searchField.getText().length();

            for (int i = 0; i < nameBlock.length; i++)
            {
                if (textlength <= nameBlock[i].length())
                {
                    if(nameBlock[i].toLowerCase().contains(searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        Log.i("VirtuFriendList", "List recyling in process... ");
                        friendList.add(new Friend(nameBlock[i], descBlock[i], imageBlock[i]));
                    }
                  }
            }
            AppendList(friendList);
            }
    });


}
public void AppendList(ArrayList<Friend> freind) {
    setListAdapter(new VirtuAdapter(this));
} 
public class VirtuAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Activity content;
    public VirtuAdapter(Activity context)
    {
        this.content = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return friendList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return friendList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return friendList.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView myTitle;
        TextView myDescription;
        ImageView myImage;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            myImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            myTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            myDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mutualTitle);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null) 
        {
            // If it is visible to the user, deploy the row(s) - allocated in local memory
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)content .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            Log.d("VIRTU", "Row deployed...");
        }
        else 
        {
            // Recycle the row if it is not visible to to the user - store in local memory
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            Log.d("VIRTU", "Row recycled...");
        }
        Friend temp = friendList.get(position);

        // Set the resources for each component in the list
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.getImage());
        holder.myTitle.setText(temp.getName());
        holder.myDescription.setText(temp.getDesc());

    return row;
    }
}
```

I have 10 elements in each string array. Resulting in that, 10 elements should be created in the ListView... However, only 5 prevails...

Anyone have any suggestions?
LogCat:

```
D/VIRTU(788): Row deployed...    
I/System.out(788): SIZESIZE:10  
D/VIRTU(788): SIZE:10   
D/VIRTU(788): Row deployed...    
I/System.out(788): SIZESIZE:10   
D/VIRTU(788): SIZE:10   
06-14 03:01:52.546: D/VIRTU(788): Row deployed...  
06-14 03:01:52.546: I/System.out(788): SIZESIZE:10   
06-14 03:01:52.546: D/VIRTU(788): SIZE:10   
06-14 03:01:52.565: D/VIRTU(788): Row deployed...  
06-14 03:01:52.565: I/System.out(788): SIZESIZE:10   
06-14 03:01:52.565: D/VIRTU(788): SIZE:10   
06-14 03:01:52.585: D/VIRTU(788): Row deployed...
```

Comment: By the way, before anyone comments. The "imageBlock[i]" where it's commented out... "imageBlock = res..." there is an array further up that provides the references to each 10 image resources...

Comment: debug your code and check size of `friendList` in `getCount` method

Comment: check properly what the `getItem` returns 10 or 5.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I've just added about 100 elements and it still only deploys 5. I'll debug it now with getCount and get back to you asap.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Okay, so I debugged it and apprently the size is 10. And 10 elements are being added to the ArrayList. So confused???

Comment: Adapters only create as many views as are currently on screen, then create more as you scroll down. Are the other views being created as you scroll?

Comment: As @DaveMorrissey says, getView is only called when the view is displayed on screen or recycle. If only 5 elements are shown on screen getView will be called 7 times. 5 for the displayed screen and two times for the first and last elements of the display. If at the top or bottom of the list then getView is called 6 times if 5 are displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
public class VirtuAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context content;
        private ArrayList<Friend> friendList;
        public VirtuAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Friend> friendList)
        {
            this.content = context;
            this.friendList = friendList;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return friendList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return friendList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return friendList.size();
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            TextView myTitle;
            TextView myDescription;
            ImageView myImage;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(view == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = LayoutInflater.from(content).inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null, false);
                holder.myImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                holder.myTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.myDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mutualTitle);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            }
            holder.myImage.setImageResource(friendList.get(position).getImage());
            holder.myTitle.setText(friendList.get(position).getName());
            holder.myDescription.setText(friendList.get(position).getDesc());

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right... This is bizare, I changed the focusable on the Buttons that are in the list to false. This is what somehow... Caused the problem... Now they are being displayed properly, but... Now I can't select any item in my list?